# Structs vector c

Tags: c, vector, struct

Okay, this was suppose to be a very simple operation, but I just can't get it to work (even though I have made it work plenty of times).

The thing is that I have a struct:

```
typedef struct vector {
unsigned long n;   /* length of vector                     */
double * v;        /* pointer to array of length n         */
} vector_t;
```

And then I am looking at an array b:

```
double B[1*10] = { 0.8650,0.9084,0.3812,0.1048, 0.0838,-0.0082,0.0987,0.4576,0.7458,1.1417};
```

On this array I do some operations, and I Then wish to save the 3 first elements in a vector_t x. I can easily print out the 3 elements, but if i try to save them in the vector_t I get an segmentation 11 fault:

```
printf(" %lf %lf %lf", B[0],B[1],B[2]);

vector_t * x = NULL;
x->n = 3;
x->v[0]=B[0];
x->v[1]=B[1];
x->v[2]=B[2];
```

I also tried doing without pointers but that didn't work either. I really can't see what should be wrong.

Comment: I guess your problem is, that you set your pointer `null` and then you try to access it. You will need to use `malloc`.

Comment: Think carefully about what this means: `vector_t * x = NULL;`.

Comment: at first I just wrote vector_t x; But then terminal said that i should add the = NULL

Comment: Read about [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) in C99

Comment: add x->v = malloc(x->n * sizeof(double) before assigning to v[0..]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do what you want you have to actually allocate space for your vector.

```
vector_t * x = malloc(sizeof(vector_t));
x->n = 3;
x->v = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
x->v[0]=B[0];
x->v[1]=B[1];
x->v[2]=B[2];
```

You must also be sure you `free` the space you allocate with `malloc` when you are done with it

```
free(x->v);
free(x);
```